# Распространенные и нераспространенные предложения

Tags: синтаксис

Известно, что в русском языке есть распространенные предложения и нераспространенные. В нераспространенных есть только подлежащее и сказуемое, а распространенных - еще и другие члены предложения. А как быть с предложениями, в которых присутствуют не только главные члены предложения, но нет второстепенных? Например, "Кот ест" - типичное нераспространенное предложение. А как быть с предложением "К счастью, кот ест"? "К счастью", насколько я понимаю, не является второстепенным членом предложения, но и под определение нераспространенного данное предложение уже не подходит.
Как быть?

Answer (score 1):

Предложение вида "К счастью, дождь кончился" является нераспространенным (содержит только предикативную основу), но осложненным (содержит вводное слово).

К осложняющим элементам относят однородные и обособленные члены, вводные и вставные конструкции, обращения.